# Docker containers cannot connect to the Internet

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have physically moved my server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) from one network to another (so I changed IPaddress/netmask/gateway/DNSs). As soon as I restarted it, *the same Docker containers cannot connect to the Internet anymore*.

This is the configuration of the bridge network

***username@hostname:~$ sudo docker inspect bridge***

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "f3d9b8da0a6a3d735c9045846eae7ee34afe8c68a6873bbb8a91c2318c946629",
        "Created": "2019-08-13T04:54:13.643422223+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "b12deba1ead80f43d09db8b5542dbfd52e0d2c340e3c36cbb537a60687e30fe0": {
                "Name": "container1",
                "EndpointID": "b17e3b047efaad714e922adc32cd731bbea120b8755ffc0c1c799687cf4af73d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

and this is the configuration of the interface

***username@hostname:~$ ip addr show***

```
117: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:91:dc:0c:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If start a busy box
***username@hostname:~$ docker run -itd --name=container1 busybox***

and I attach to it
***username@hostname:~$ docker attach container1***

and I ping the world
***/ # ping -w3 8.8.8.8***

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

so no response back, while I can successfully ping a different busy box container.

Just to to provide more info, these are the IP names that the busybox container recognises:

```
***/ # cat /etc/hosts***
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  b12deba1ead8
```

and the route from inside the container
***/ # ip route show***

```
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link  src 172.17.0.2
```

I can ping the gateway from inside the container (***/ # ping -w 4 172.17.0.1***), and I can also successfully ping the IP address of my server (***/ # ping -w 4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx***).

Clearly I have this problem with all the containers,  not only busybox: for example, also by opening a shell in an alpine docker container I cannot pass through bridge.

My initial guess was it could be a firewall problem, but if I "sudo ufw disable" nothing changes.

Other possible parameters I checked are
***username@hostname:~$  sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding***

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

So everything looks fine to me so far. I also removed and reinstalled the docker daemon, but still the same problem.

What the problem could be? Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to ping the docker interface from inside the container? (In your case 172.17.0.1 and the ip address from your network interface from inside your container (dont know the ip address; i think the interface name should be ens32)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can ping the gateway from inside the container (/ # ping -w 4 172.17.0.1), and I can also successfully ping the IP address of my server (/ # ping -w 4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). But still I cannot ping the world: with 8.8.8.8 (and other addresses), I have 100% packet loss.